# how to extend the UrlHlper to attach a new method to it in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to extend the UrlHelper in asp.net Mvc but I do not know what is the issue in my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace workflow.helpers
{
    public static class CustomUrls
    {

            public static string baseUrl(this UrlHelper helper)
            {
                return String.Format("/workflow");
            }
    }
}
```

I do not know why I can't see the new method in the Intel sense.

> Edit, Web.Config File

```
<namespaces>
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  <add namespace="workflow.helpers" />
</namespaces>
```

Comment: Have you included a using statement (`@using workflow.helpers;`) in the view?

Comment: Or you can add the namespace in your web.config

Comment: I already added it in the web.config :(

Comment: Show the relevant section of the web.config file

Comment: Tested and works fine for me. Try restarting VS.

Comment: @StephenMuecke is it enough just to create the class and to add the namespace in the web.config or should I do something further?

Comment: @AhmNaim, I just copied your code into my project, added the name space to both web.config files, restarted VS and it worked fine (I got intellisense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks I got it, it works after I restarted VS

Answer (score 2):

First include this line in your view:

```
@using workflow.helpers
```

Then you can use it in the view:

```
@Url.BaseUrl()
```